# checkbox checked in JQuery is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I've a simple situation. 
When the `checkbox` is checked then the `textbox` is shown. Unchecking `checkbox` will hide the `textbox`.

I move the value to (`asp:Textbox`) textboxA.text and set the (`asp:Checkbox`) "chkboxA" to Checked in Server side (Page load).

then my `jquery` code `document.ready` is executed.

`C#` code behind

```
 protected override void OnLoad()
    {   textboxA.Text = "Hello World";
        chkboxA.Checked = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxA.Text);
    }

JQUERY CODE:

$('input[id$=chkboxA]').click(function () {
    var checked_status = this.checked;
    if (checked_status == true) {
        $('input[id$=textboxA]').show();
    }
    else {
        $('input[id$=textboxA]').hide();
    }
});

$('input[id$=chkboxA]').click();  //this statment triggers the checkbox checked
```

PROBLEM:
When the page is first shown the "`textboxA`" is shown but the `checkboxA` is `unchecked`. 
Then when I click on the `checkboxA` the `checkbox` is  checked and the `TextboxA` remains on the screen. 
Then when I click on the `CheckboxA` again to uncheck then the `texboxA` is not shown.

so the issue is on first load (first shown on the screen).

Why is the `checkboxA` not checked when the page is first shown while the `TextboxA` is shown?

what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Show more server-side code. Maybe somewhere after the Page_Load you are modify the chkboxA.Checked property value. By the way, better use `$("#<%= control.ClientID %>")` selector for server controls instead of the `$('[id$=ID]')`

Comment: @Yuriy : I thought about it but I've put the in external JS file. and that's not working. I think I need to put in ASPX file self in script tag, which I don't want. Have you tried to put  "control.ClientID " in external js file (reference file) ? does it work for you? (not in ASPX file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think easiest way is to use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

try something like this

Initially set the `visible` `false` in `textbox`

```
    $(".chk").click(function() {
    $(".txt").toggle(this.checked);
    });
```

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/1880/

Comment: I've set the visible=false in aspx,  then used " $('input[id$=textboxA]').toggle(this.checked);"  but now it doesn't switch neither shown on the first display.. even check/uncheck doesn't show.

Comment: Have you look the jsfiddle?  since you using asp.net i preffer to use class. so set Cssclass for both text box and check box, and use those classes in javascript.

Comment: i have updated the answer. That shoud work in your application

Comment: .Visible = false in ASP.NET will actually not render the control entirely. So it's never on the page. You'll have to do .Style.Add("display", "none") because jQuery works with the display property of the style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about it:
Instead of,

```
chkboxA.Checked = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxA.Text);
```

you could have a script that is executed once the page is done loading (in you markup)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if($('#textboxA').attr('value') != '') {
            $('#chkboxA').attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $('#chkboxA').attr("checked", false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Then, when evaluating whether the checkbox is checked, you could use:

```
$('#chkboxA').click(function () {

    if (this.attr('checked')) {
        $('#textboxA').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#textboxA').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I prefer keeping the statement in Asp.NET server side for checkbox checked, since I have to retrieve the value from the DB move to textbox and and I can set the checked value there too for the textbox rather then test in client side (the code is more collected - just my preference). I just don't want to do postback for show/hide textbox.

Comment: @mesut: I am not sure I understand. None of the statements above do a postback. They all execute on the client-side

Comment: I meant I don't want to put the extra code in JS file, I prefer using this code "chkboxA.Checked = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textboxA.Text);   ".

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line :

```
if ($('input[id$=chkboxA]').is(':checked')) {
    $('input[id$=textboxA]').show();
}
else {
    $('input[id$=textboxA]').hide();
}
```

after :

```
$('input[id$=chkboxA]').click();
```

If you remove : `$('input[id$=chkboxA]').click();` you will see that textbox will hidden.

Comment: This is not working for me, not on first load and not on switching... so I'm not sure what the problem is maybe I need to use class as huMpty advice.

Comment: @mesut sorry, i was have mistake, try now, but don't delete your code, its working with me, just "add" my code under `$('input[id$=chkboxA]').click();` directly.